# Needing help Assets\FlyLittleBird.cs(7,27): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, syntax-error

I am making flappy bird in unity and need help this is the code i am working on and the error code is Assets\FlyLittleBird.cs(7,27): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlyLittleBird : MonoBehaviour {
    
    public float velocity - 1;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Jump
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * velocity;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `public float velocity - 1;` should probably rather be `public float velocity = -1;`

Comment: Thank you that worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the 7th line of your code
i.e. public float velocity - 1;
You must correct it as-
public float velocity = 1;

Comment: Note that obvious typo-based questions are off-topic since it won't help anyone else in the future -> [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)